# XIB-instantiated Object's IBOutlet is nil

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller, iboutlet

I have a XIB set up like in this screenshot:

[alt text http://emberapp.com/jxpx777/images/interface-builder/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/jxpx777/images/interface-builder/sizes/m.png)

File's owner is my main window controller. The XIB is also in charge of creating an object that serves as the delegate for the [MGScopeBar](http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGScopeBar/) view. As you can see in the screenshot, the scope bar delegate has an `IBOutlet` for the search field so that it can return it as an extra view as part of the delegate process.

The problem I'm having is that when the delegate object is queried for the accessory view, the `IBOutlet` `NSSearchField` is nil. I'm fairly certain this has something to do with the order that objects are created, IBOutlets wired, etc, but I'm just a little lost as to where in the process I can expect the search field to exist so that the scope bar delegate can reference it properly.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19), it looks like all of the outlets in a NIB/XIB are supposed to be wired before `awakeFromNib` is called on any object in that NIB/XIB, but that outlets <s>probably</s> are not wired when `init`, etc., are called on the objects.

Comment: No “probably” about it. Outlets are set via KVC (iPhone) or behavior very much like it (Mac). That can only happen *after* the object has been allocated *and* initialized. Think about how you might do it if you were implementing the nib loader; it'd be something like: `id instance = [[[objectClass alloc] initWithCoder:unarchiver] autorelease]; for (NSString *k in objectOutlets) [instance setValue:[objectOutlets objectForKey:k] forKey:k]; [instance awakeFromNib];` Notice that `initWithCoder:` returns before outlet-setting begins; no outlets are set yet while `initWithCoder:` is running.